# Unity Facebook accept invitation from with URL?

Tags: facebook

I read on Facebook documentation 
"On iOS and Android devices, if the player has the Facebook app installed and push notifications enabled, they will receive a push notification alerting them to the request. The push notification will open the Facebook app and will display the request inside the notification jewel in a similar way to on desktop.

Accepting the request will direct the recipient to the app on their device if installed or to the appropriate location (Apple App Store or Google Play) to download the app otherwise."
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.3

But how to set the direct link to Apple store of Google Play? When I try to accept the invitation, facebook direct me to invalid page.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. The reason is that I don't turn on Single Sign On and Deep Linking in Android/iOS platform on facebook developer app settings.